# How to test navigation in flutter using test driver?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a login page, and i am writing a test case to check if on click of login button the home screen is opened or not using flutter test driver.

```
        await driver.tap(userNameTextField);
        await driver.enterText(testdata[testCaseCounter][0]);
        await driver.tap(passwordTextField);
        await driver.enterText(testdata[testCaseCounter][1]);
        await driver.tap(buttonLogin);
        await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey("HomeScreen"));
```

The above code inputs the right username and password , but on loading into home screen, the waitFor command fails to identify the "HomeScreen" key.

Comment: What error do you see ? Mean time, you can provide a custom timeout duration in `waitFor` command.  `await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey("HomeScreen"), timeout: Duration(seconds: 30));`  or wait till the app / screen becomes stable by telling driver to `waitUntilNoTransientCallbacks()` before your `waitFor` command. Hope it helps.